# Is there a way to know all the files present in a p4 branch

Tags: python, version-control, perforce, p4v

I have a requirement where once a perforce branch is provided,I need to open all the files present in that branch and check for some content,is there a p4 command or python way to do this?Please provide inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to search for specified content in a certain set of files, 'p4 grep' should do the job nicely: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/grep.html#1040665